# set Value of TextField on button click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to set the value of TextField when a user clicks on a button.

The error I am getting is:

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

I think it has to do with the Button as I have a onclick function for each one. maybe there a better solution?

```
const [txtValue, setTxtValue] = useState({})


 function campaignAmount(value){
       // alert(value)
       
            setTxtValue(value);
    }




    return (
<Grid container>
                            <Grid item lg={6}>
                        <ButtonGroup color="primary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
                            <Button onclick={campaignAmount(300)}>$300</Button>
                            <Button onclick={campaignAmount(500)}>$500</Button>
                            <Button onclick={campaignAmount(1000)}>$1000</Button>
                        </ButtonGroup>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item lg={3}>
                        <TextField
                            id="campaignAmount"
                            name="campaignAmount"
                            margin="none"
                            fullWidth
                            value={`${txtValue[0]}`=== "undefined" ? '0' : `${txtValue[0]}`}
                            variant="outlined"
                            required={true}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        </Grid>
);
```

Update:
I have made some changes and now I am getting

```
  Line 164:9:  'setTextValue' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

New Code

```
 const [txtValue, setTxtValue] = useState("0")
  function schemaTypeSelectionHandle(event) {

        // console.log('key: ', $(event.target).data('key'));
        setTextValue(event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('data-key').value);
        console.log('key: ', event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('data-key').value);
      }




    return (
     <Grid container>
                        <Grid item lg={6}>
                    <ButtonGroup color="primary"  onClick={this.schemaTypeSelectionHandle.bind(this)} aria-label="outlined primary button group">
                        <Button data-key='1'>$300</Button>
                        <Button data-key='1'>$500</Button>
                        <Button data-key='1'>>$1000</Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item lg={3}>
                    <TextField
                        id="campaignAmount"
                        name="campaignAmount"
                        margin="none"
                        fullWidth
                        value={`${txtValue[0]}`=== "undefined" ? '0' : `${txtValue[0]}`}
                        variant="outlined"
                        required={true}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    </Grid>
);
```

Comment: it could be easier to catch up with your problem if you reproduce this on codesandbox

Comment: That would be great, if we used App but we don't and codesandbox seems to never accept my function codes.

Comment: the state setter is `setTxtValue`. `setTextValue` is not defined in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edited code seems to be working fine. But the only issue is the little typo you have. It is "setTxtValue"  not "setTextValue".

Your defined hook => *`const [txtValue, setTxtValue] = useState("0")`*

Comment: Correct - just seems to still have a data-key issue.